# display message on page after validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following entry in my html file. basically the use of this entry is to show a message on page when user will hover the mouse on input field. now i want to show the same message, so i decided to put the same validation in javascript. then I am not able to display the message box please help.

```
.field:hover .hint {  
    position: absolute;
    display: block;  
    margin: -30px 0 0 455px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    background: #FFFC17;

    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px; 
    }

<TR> 
    <TD><label for="name"><bean:message key="addEmail"/></label><div style="float:left">
  <div class="field"><html:text property="emailid" maxlength="150" size="40" style="color=#7D2252" styleClass="input"></html:text>
  <p class="hint"><bean:message key="addEmailMsg"/></p></div>
  </div>
  </TD>
    </TR>
```

we can see the entry of div tag. and hint class. please help me
basically I am java programmer and have not implemented too much javascript and css. Thanks

Comment: It's likely there is a bug in your javascript code. You should post the relevant sections here as well.

Answer (score 0):

instead of css, you can make js function and put it in mouseover event

```
function show_hint(){
var hint = document.getElementById('hint');
hint.style.display = "block";
}
```

and make hint like

```
<p id="hint"><bean:message key="addEmailMsg"/></p>
```

and make event

```
<div class="field" onmouseover="show_hint();"></div>
```

### or just use jquery with making 'hint' hidden

**html**

```
<p id="hint" style="display:none;"><bean:message key="addEmailMsg"/></p>
```

**js**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".field").hover(
          function () {
            $('.hint').show();

        }); });
```